# Check if ID exists in database

Tags: php, mysql

How can i check if a id exists in a mysql database, and if it does: create a new id and check over again. I have the following code to create a id:

```
$length = 10;
$id = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $id .= chr(rand(ord('0'), ord('9')));
}
```

To check if the id exists i use the code below:

```
$database->query('SELECT user_id FROM users 
                  WHERE public_id = ':public_id',array(':public_id' => $public_id)');

if($database->count() >= '1') { 
//create a new id 
} else { }
```

Comment: Beware [TOCTOU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) errors, what are you using this id for and why is it random?

Comment: Is the 'id' column the primary key? If it is you could use something like [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) to check for a duplicate key and create a new entry if it already exists in one statement. But still not sure of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Why would you need to "check over again"? Once it's inserted into the database, you know it's in there.

Comment: @Matt - I think he means that if the ID is in use, he can generate a new ID and check that one.

Comment: @andrewsi I understand that; what I don't understand is *why* OP would need to check to see if the ID he just entered is in the database.

Comment: THe id is the public id that are visibil for the user. There is alleredy a main id which is not visibil for the user. This would be used when the user are registered. The checking part will be used to check if the random created id are alleredy in use. And if it is: it will create a new id. Is this a wrong way to approach ?

Comment: Use a function to create unique ideas?

Comment: Why use a random string for it instead of say some function based on their userid, for example, userid 1 is public id `1234561`, userid 10 is public id `1234570`

Comment: @Ukjent - so essentially you've got `user_id`, which is the primary key of the table and so unique; and then `public_id` which is a username, is generated randomly?

Comment: @andrewsi the user_id is the primary key(auto_incremented) and not visibil for the user. The username can be set manually by the user, and the public is a visibil id mostly used if the user need to feks contact the support and get referenced by the id. I suppose i maybe can create a auto increment on the public id and start it at 0235926 or something like that

Comment: @Ukjent - Is there a reason why you're keeping the user_id concealed?

Comment: Just some small features where i want two separate ids, 1 visibil and 1 not :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not considered a "best practice", as (theoretically) you could create an infinite loop (creating a random ID, then checking for existence could "hit" on each iteration).

A better solution to create unique IDs is to set a column as your primary key, and increment upon each new insert.

If you want another column to be unique, you can define that column to be unique as well, but you won't have to rely on "random" strings.

Comment: The problem is not the theoretical infinite loop, but that `UNIQUE` constraint that blocks `INSERT` calls with an error with only one query required. This is superior to a `SELECT` then `INSERT` which is additionally prone to race conditions. Without a `UNIQUE` index, there's no guarantee of uniqueness.

Comment: +1 for that, @tadman. Your comment is more accurate than my answer. Although I knew that to be true, I didn't explain it as such. Thank you!